# Getting Python2 exec behaviour in python3: UnboundLocalError: local variable

Tags: python-3.x

I am using some old code base that was initially written in python2. The devs say they have ported it to python3 however I found a all the code that uses `exec` is completely broken. Below you can find an example like the one I am trying to fix:

```py
def function_with_exec(table):

    (sess, tgt) = 3, None
    try:
        exec("ec = some_object.{}_get_entry_count(sess_hdl=sess, dev_tgt=tgt)".
             format(table))
    except AttributeError:
        return []

    ec = some_function(ec)
```

When running this code, I get: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ec' referenced before assignment.

I have been reading that a way to modify the global `ec` variable from the `exec` function is to pass the `globals()` as second argument. However, when I do that, then the variables `sess` and `tgt` which are also used in the expression, become undefined too.

I really do not find a way to solve this.

Comment: Exec just runs a Python command from a string.  If your statement is valid when typed in Python 3 it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python thinks `ec` is a local variable, which hasn't yet been assigned to, and you can't reference it before first assigning to it. Use the `global` statement at the start of your function, like so:

```py
def function_with_exec(table):
    # ec now refers to the global variable, which presumedly already been as
    global ec
    (sess, tgt) = 3, None
    try:
        exec("ec = some_object.{}_get_entry_count(sess_hdl=sess, dev_tgt=tgt)".
             format(table))
    except AttributeError:
        return []
    
    ec = some_function(ec)
```

See [7.12. The global statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement)

> The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals. It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global.

You could also remove the call to `exec` by using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) instead:

```py
def function_with_exec():
    global ec
    
    (sess, tgt) = 3, None
    try:
        ec = getattr(some_object, f"{table}_get_entry_count")(sess_hdl=sess, 
                                                              dev_tgt=tgt)
    except AttributeError:
        return []
    
    ec = some_function(ec)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that the getattr would be even a better solution for all this mess. Thanks a lot!